# Permissions for specific object instance to another in Django

Tags: python-3.4, django-1.7, django-permissions

after I went through the [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization) and other people's questions in the same topic. still, I couldn't find the solution!!

I need each instance of User object to have a permission to Edit another specific instance object(I created the Model).

once the User instance object created the other instance object will be created and assigned to it.

for example: there is a user object and

```
class image(models.Model):
    titel = models.CharField()
    img = models.ImageField()
```

a user with the ID=x can edit an image with the ID=x

how to do that?

Comment: question is unclear, can you explain it with test case?

Comment: Hi Kishor .. I added a small example

Comment: img_obj.img = "some image" img_obj.save() not working?